# org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound : Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring MVC. I tried creating small hello world app but it is not running as expected. 
I am always getting error
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/FitnessTracker/greeting.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'fitTrackerServlet'

I know this error is very common and there are lots of links available on the google but none of them worked for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code snippet

**HelloController.java**

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting")    
public String sayHello(Model model) {
model.addAttribute("greeting","Hello World!!!!");
return "hello";
}}
```

**hello.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>
Insert title here
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
${greeting}
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**fitTrackerServlet-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.firstspringmvc.controller"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" 
        p:suffix=".jsp"/>
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

**Project Structure**
[image]

Comment: Try adding your XML as an init-param to your servlet defintion with name "contextConfigLocation" and value the path of the XML.
It may just not loaded the Controller definition.

Comment: `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` give url pattern like this and try once..U have jsp pages here not html in jsp applications

Comment: @helospark I have tried this as well but didn't work

Comment: @Hema I don't think so html or jsp hv to do anything with the error I am getting.

Comment: I faced issue with tht once.. You can try once if needed

Answer (score 0):

The URL `/greeting` does not have any `.html` at the end, so the servlet will not going to use the DispatcherServlet, because `*.html` pattern does not match the /greeting, and this will result in 404.

Change your web.xml such:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```